# Calculating trends with `emtrends` for three-way interaction model results in same slope estimates

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, lsmeans, marginal-effect

I have fit a multilevel gam (`mgcv`) that includes a three-way interaction between a continuous variable (`prev.rain`) and two categorical variables (`level` and `roya_present`). The model also has some random effects (`quadrat`, `plantID`, and `year`) as well as a global and group-level smoothers based on `month` and `month`/`level`, respectively. I treat all the random effects and smoothers as nuisance variables when calculating trends with `emtrends`.

Here is the formula for the model:

```
level_bam7 <- bam(pa ~ scale(prev.rain) * level * roya_present + 
                        scale(days.elapse) +
                        s(month, k=5, bs="cc") +
                        s(month, level, k=5, bs="fs") +
                        s(plantID, k=582, bs="re") +
                        s(quadrat, k=127, bs="re") + s(year, k=4, bs="re"),
                family = binomial, 
                data = roya_1_long)
```

When I use the following code to calculate the slopes of `prev.rain` at each `level` and `roya_present` level:

```
emtrends(level_bam7, specs = c("level", "roya_present"), var = "prev.rain", 
         nuisance = c("quadrat", "plantID"))
```

I get the same values at each factor combination:

```
 level  roya_present prev.rain.trend   SE    df lower.CL upper.CL
 bottom            0            3.37 1.98 18882   -0.504     7.24
 mid               0            3.37 1.98 18882   -0.504     7.24
 top               0            3.37 1.98 18882   -0.504     7.24
 bottom            1            3.37 1.98 18882   -0.504     7.24
 mid               1            3.37 1.98 18882   -0.504     7.24
 top               1            3.37 1.98 18882   -0.504     7.24

Results are averaged over the levels of: 2 nuisance factors, year 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

I thought it might be because there is smooth effect of `month` varying by `level`, so it might be important to specify by `month`. So when I try:

```
emtrends(level_bam7, specs = c("level", "roya_present"), var = "prev.rain", 
         nuisance = c("quadrat", "plantID"), at = list(month = c(1,6)))
```

I still get the same result, though `month` is listed among the levels that results are averaged over. I believe the slopes should differ by these factor levels and calculating the marginal means over `prev.rain` seems to support this. What am I missing to be able to calculate and compare these slopes?

Comment: I wonder if `scale()` is messing things up. It is a surprisingly temperamental function. Plus if you want slopes for `prev.rain`, it seems a bit odd to scale it in the model.

Comment: Thank you for the response @RussLenth, sorry it took a while for me to get back to this. It seems like the behavior of `emtrends` has changed though, and I no longer have the issue reported here. On the other hand, the same code no longer reports estimates for `roya_present == 1`, nor does it seem to recognize the arguments defining nuisance variables (The notes at the bottom read "averaged over 0 nuisance variables". Has there been an update to `emmeans` that might have caused this?

Comment: I did change the drivers for `gam` models quite a bit recently, as I learned that some smoothers actually create random effects but those were being included in the reference grid, unlike other models. And there were additional issues that came up along with that. You can see some of the traffic on this by looking at [Issue #365](https://github.com/rvlenth/emmeans/issues/365) in the GitHub site, which also references some others. This definitely affects your model, as the "fs" and "bs" smooths are regarded as random. Neither quadrat nor plantID are in the reference grid now.